# How can i check in the background if a specific date and time is reached in Android

Tags: android, date, time, background, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make a program that checks in the background if a specific date and time is reached. I want to save the date and time in a SharedPreference. The SharedPreferences isn't the problem but i need to know how to make an service that is running in the background and also checks if the date and time in the SharedPreference is equal to the date and time at the current moment. I also need to start the service on boot. This is what i have now:

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="Receiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".Service"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

**Receiver**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, Service.class));
}
```

**Service**

```
SharedPreferences prefs;

public Service() {
    super("Service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("nl.martijnvk.declareerassistent", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Prashanth i got it to work with the AlarmManager class, but the calculation of the milliseconds are not correct. In my log he prints a value of 1469632151229 but my calendar is set to just a minute later. What is the problem?

Comment: Checkout alarm manager class

Comment: Hi, what are you setting to calender. I didn't get you. Just milli seconds?

Comment: It  should work perfect. May be android os is delaying. For a threshold you can schedule before some milliseconds.

Comment: Can you post your code of setting calender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

  calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
  calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
  calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 13);

  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 48);
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

  Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

create broadcast receiver which will be triggered

```
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   // it is triggered on the time you scheduled 

}
```

}

Comment: So with the 1st code i set the Receiver and the receiver is triggered when the date is reached? And then in the OnReceive i have to put the code to execute when the date is reached? Or do i have to insert the compare code in the onReceive?

Comment: No need to check again as you are scheduling the event for your time.

Comment: I tried this, with a Toast in the OnReceive event but when the TimeofDay reaches the calendar time, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you know how to use Shared Preference,

1. Than you can read the Date from SharedPreference in String form.
2. Then you need to convert that String in the Date object:

   public static Date getDateFromString(String dateString, String format){
      Date date = null;
      try {
          if (dateString != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
      }
      return date;
   }

**Note: here String format can be any of the Pattern you saved in SharedPref.
[SimpleDateFormat Pattern examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**

3. Get the current Date.

   Date currentDate = new Date();
4. Then you can compare the two dates using any of below methods.

   public static boolean isEqualiOrBefore(Date baseDate, Date dateToCompare) {

   ```
       try {

         return (baseDate.equals(dateToCompare) || baseDate.before(dateToCompare));
       }
       catch (NullPointerException npe) {

         return false;
       }
     }

    public static boolean isEqualiOrAfter(Date baseDate, Date dateToCompare) {

       try {

         return (baseDate.equals(dateToCompare) || baseDate.after(dateToCompare));
       }
       catch (NullPointerException npe) {

         return false;
       }
     }

    public static boolean isEquali(Date baseDate, Date dateToCompare) {

       try {

         return (baseDate.equals(dateToCompare));
       }
       catch (NullPointerException npe) {

         return false;
       }
     }
   ```

Comment: This give answer to the question how to comapare dates, but it doens't answer the question how to keep checking this in the background.

Comment: You can write a timer task to execute above code after some predefined time interval in your service.